# Push Notifications to tags in BlueMix

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am trying to use the messages service in the **Bluemix Services Push REST API** to send a push notification to users who are subscribed to previously created tags. The problem is that when I send a notification to multiple tags, if a user is registered to more than one of those tags he is receiving the same notification multiple times.

The API says this:

```
tagNames (Array[string], optional): Send notification to the devices that have subscribed to any of these tags
```

So I understand that the user should only receive one notification, instead of what is happening.

My call looks like this:

```
{
    "message": { 
        "alert": "Text notification",
    }, 
    "target": { 
        "tagNames": ["TAG1","TAG2","TAG3","TAG4","TAG5","TAG6","TAG7"] 
    },
    "settings": {
        "apns": {
            "badge": 1,
            "sound": "UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed with the Bluemix Push development team that this is indeed a defect in the service and you should only be receiving one notification in this instance. The team has created a defect for the issue and once it has been resolved and pushed to production I'll update this answer with whatever additional information or changes in usage come from the fix.

Thank you very much for bringing this to our attention

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :)